# How to trigger only server side click event if button have both client and server side click event using javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have one server side button control as bellow...

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" class="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="Rechercher" onClientClick="javascript:SelectAnnonceBySearchRepeater(1);" OnClick="BtnSearchClk" />
```

Here onClientClick is calling client side javascript function and onClick is calling serverside click event in code behind which is on same button.

Now i want to trigger only server side click event which is code behind click event from client side javascript function using javascript or jQuery how to achieve this ?

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT

I have tried this.

```
$("#Button1").trigger("click");
```

But this will fire both client and server side click event.

Comment: return true in client side function should work...

Comment: Not ajax , want to call .cs  page function from javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(yourButtonId, string.Empty) %>;
```